# "Until end of touch do..." script for a web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, while-loop

I am creating a web app for the iPhone and I stumbled upon a problem. So far I have only seen TouchStart, TouchEnd, TouchMove and TouchCancel. Is there any function that would combine a "loop while" with TouchStart? That is if there's a code that would continue to do an action until you stop touching the screen.

So what I want to combine is this:

```
while( /*CONDITION*/ )
```

and

```
$(' *#ID* ').bind( "touchstart", function(e){ /*CODE*/ });
```

I'm not very good at Javascript yet so I can't really figure out how to do this myself. I have also searched for a solution on Google, but with no results. Is there even any way of combining a function with loop? Am I trying to accomplish the impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As JavaScript is single-threaded, a `while` loop would result in freezing the interface as soon as the touch started. But you can simulate that with a timer:

```
var timer;
$('#ID').bind("touchstart", function(e){
    clearInterval(timer); // stop the timer (if any)
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        // do something every 100ms
    }, 100);
});
$('#ID').bind("touchend touchcancel", function(e){
    clearInterval(timer); // stop the timer
});
```

Comment: You might want to add `touchcancel` to the second handler so it's for both `touchend` and `touchcancel`. Then again, I don't know much about `touch` events...

Comment: @Ian Done. And me neither.

Comment: Haha I don't think I would've known about the `touchcancel` event if the OP didn't mention it :) And I was thinking `.bind("touchend touchcancel"` just because they will probably do the same thing, but it's not very different and not a big deal

Comment: Thanks you so much! It works perfectly! I never thought about the timer. Once again, thank you!

Comment: @Ian I wasn't sure `bind` supported multiple events, and when I saw `.bind( eventType ...` in the doc page, I just assumed it didn't. I was wrong! :)

Comment: @bfavaretto No big deal, what you had before was just as valid obviously. Just wanted to help combine :)

Comment: Man I searched for this answer for a very long time. Working great ty